# how to define custom tooltip on all elements with certain class in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I define tool tips with custom content on bulk elements like

```
<div class="my-tooltip">Who?</div>
<div class="my-tooltip">Who?</div>
<div class="my-tooltip">Who?</div>
```

and then something in js I define my tooltip title and everything with just js?

Instead of doing like this

```
<div class="my-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Me, Yes!">Who?</div>
<div class="my-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Me, Yes!">Who?</div>
<div class="my-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Me, Yes!">Who?</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger the tooltips via JavaScript ([docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-usage)):

```
$('#example').tooltip(options);
```

Your case ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxtjr39b/17/)):

```
<div class="my-tooltip">Who?</div>
<div class="my-tooltip">Who?</div>
<div class="my-tooltip">Who?</div>

$('.my-tooltip').tooltip({
  title: "Me, Yes!",
  placement: "bottom"
});
```

Comment: Thanks, That's the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Do like this .You could add using [`attr({attrname:value})`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) of jquery.create the attribute names and values as a object

```js
$('.my-tooltip').attr({
  'data-toggle': "tooltip",
  'data-placement': "bottom",
  'title': "Me, Yes!"
})
console.log($('body').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-tooltip">Who?</div>
<div class="my-tooltip">Who?</div>
<div class="my-tooltip">Who?</div>
```